# Building a multidimensional object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've these buttons:

```
<button data-action="book-unit" data-room_id="123" data-room_name="Apartment #" data-room_nights_nb="1" date-room_nights_list="2019-06-07" data-room_night_price="110.00">...</button>

<button data-action="book-unit" data-room_id="124" data-room_name="House #" data-room_nights_nb="1" date-room_nights_list="2019-06-07" data-room_night_price="125.00">...</button>
```

I need to create the following object from these buttons:

```
{
    '123' : {
        'room_name' : 'Apartment #12',
        'room_nights_nb' : '1',
        'room_nights_list' : '2019-06-07',
        'room_night_price' : '110.00'
    },
    '124' : {
        'room_name' : 'House #2',
        'room_nights_nb' : '1',
        'room_nights_list' : '2019-06-07',
        'room_night_price' : '125.00'
    }
}
```

This is what I've try before posting here:
var BOO_UnitsList = new Array();

```
$('.btn-success').each(function(index) {
    var room_id[$(this).data('room_id')] = [
        room_id = $(this).data('room_id'), 
        room_name = $(this).data('room_name'), 
        room_nights_nb = $(this).data('room_nights_nb'), 
        room_nights_list = $(this).data('room_nights_list'), 
        room_night_price = $(this).data('room_night_price')
    ];

    console.log(room_id[$(this).data('room_id')]);
});
```

Comment: what you say you need is not an array.

Comment: What you show is **not** an Array. It's JS object.

Comment: If you guys are going to get technical, then javascript doesn't have arrays, it has iterable objects.

Comment: `var BOO_UnitsList = {};` and in foreach `BOO_UnitsList[$(this).data('room_id')] = { ... }`

Comment: `var room_id[$(this).data('room_id')] =`  `room_id` doesn't exist yet.  You are creating it at that point.  You should be seeing a syntax or logical error for that for trying to access an index of something that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to push into the array you want to assign the object, try something like this

```js
var obj = {};

$('.btn-success').each(function(index) {
     var room_id = $(this).data('room_id');
     var room_name = $(this).data('room_name');
     var room_nights_nb = $(this).data('room_nights_nb');
     var room_nights_list = $(this).data('room_nights_list');
     var room_night_price = $(this).data('room_night_price');

     obj[room_id] = {
        'room_name' : room_name,
        'room_nights_nb' : room_nights_nb,
        'room_nights_list' : room_nights_list,
        'room_night_price' : room_night_price
     }
});

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-action="book-unit" data-room_id="123" data-room_name="Apartment #" data-room_nights_nb="1" date-room_nights_list="2019-06-07" data-room_night_price="110.00" class="btn-success">...</button>

<button data-action="book-unit" data-room_id="124" data-room_name="House #" data-room_nights_nb="1" date-room_nights_list="2019-06-07" data-room_night_price="125.00" class="btn-success">...</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are going to trigger this, but you can use [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) to get all the attributes on the node and loop over them, then push it onto the resulting object like this:

```js
let result = {}
let btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')].forEach(btn => {
  let obj = {}
  // Items to ignore
  let ignore = ['data-action', 'data-room_id']
  // The room id
  let id = 0
  // Loop over the buttons attributes
  for (let a of btn.attributes) {
    // Get the room id
    if(a.name == 'data-room_id') id = a.value
    // If we want to ignore the value skip it
    if(ignore.includes(a.name)) continue
    // Add the item to the child object
    obj[a.name.replace(/^data-/, '')] = a.value
  }
  
  // Add the child object to the final object
  result[id] = obj
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<button data-action="book-unit" data-room_id="123" data-room_name="Apartment #" data-room_nights_nb="1" date-room_nights_list="2019-06-07" data-room_night_price="110.00">...</button>

<button data-action="book-unit" data-room_id="124" data-room_name="House #" data-room_nights_nb="1" date-room_nights_list="2019-06-07" data-room_night_price="125.00">...</button>
```